# PhpSpreadsheet formula not running in saved spreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PHPOffice/PHPSpreadsheet.

This is my code:

```
$formula = '=((E' . $row. '*G' . $row. ')+G' . $row. ')*F' . $row;
$sheet->getCell('D' . $row)->setValue($formula);
```

When I open spreadsheet, in the cell appears 0 (because formula is not calculated), but its value is `=((E7*G7)+G7)*F7`.

When I click on save icon, all formulas are automatically calculated.

I tried `$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas();` but not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `$sheet->setCellValue('D' . $row,$formula);`.

Comment: @Premlatha not working

Comment: Maybe this Documentation helps https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/calculation-engine/

Answer (score -1):

May be you can clone sheet.
For example:

```
    $clonedWorksheet = clone $spreadsheet->getSheetByName('yourSheet');
    $clonedWorksheet->setTitle('yourSheet1');
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($clonedWorksheet);
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(1);

    $formula = '=((E' . $row. '*G' . $row. ')+G' . $row. ')*F' . $row;
    $sheet->getCell('D' . $row)->setValue($formula);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation, rather than just code.